# SpriteBuilder Android Building Error : Package APK Tool Error

Tags: android, spritebuilder

I'm using SpriteBuilder to create a game. The game runs fine in any iOS device, but when I try to build for Android, I get an error "Package APK Tool Error".

SB Version: 1.4.9

SB Revision: eea568a5c7

XCode Version 6.0.1 (6A317)

The Error message which I am getting is as follows :

> FAILED: '/Library/SBAndroid/Application
>   Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Toolchains/Android.xctoolchain/lib/apportable/build_tools/aapt_package.py'
>   -R/Users/thefreebird/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/First-doujqshtxvhdhsgbiqpivulzfhbi/Build/Products/Debug-sbandroid/gen/org/cocos2d/First/R.java
>   --depfile '/Users/thefreebird/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/First-doujqshtxvhdhsgbiqpivulzfhbi/Build/Products/Debug-sbandroid/First
>   Demo Project-resources.apk.d' -S
>   /Users/thefreebird/Documents/CoCOS2dProjs/First.spritebuilder/Source/Resources/res
>   -- '/Library/SBAndroid/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Toolchains/Android.xctoolchain/usr/bin/aapt'
>   package --auto-add-overlay -m -f -M
>   /Users/thefreebird/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/First-doujqshtxvhdhsgbiqpivulzfhbi/Build/Products/Debug-sbandroid/AndroidManifest.xml
>   -I '/Library/SBAndroid/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Platforms/Android.platform/Developer/SDKs/SBAndroid.sdk/../../lib/android.jar'
>   -F '/Users/thefreebird/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/First-doujqshtxvhdhsgbiqpivulzfhbi/Build/Products/Debug-sbandroid/First
>   Demo Project-resources.apk' -J
>   /Users/thefreebird/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/First-doujqshtxvhdhsgbiqpivulzfhbi/Build/Products/Debug-sbandroid/gen
>   --generate-dependencies -S /Users/thefreebird/Documents/CoCOS2dProjs/First.spritebuilder/Source/Resources/res
>   --extra-packages org.cocos2d.First invalid resource directory name: /Users/thefreebird/Documents/CoCOS2dProjs/First.spritebuilder/Source/Resources/res/assets
>   FAILED: '/Library/SBAndroid/Application
>   Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Toolchains/Android.xctoolchain/usr/bin/dx'
>   --dex --num-threads=16 --output='/Users/thefreebird/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/First-doujqshtxvhdhsgbiqpivulzfhbi/Build/Products/Debug-sbandroid/dexed_libs/Library_SBAndroid_Application
>   Support_Developer_Shared_Xcode_Platforms_Android.platform_Developer_SDKs_SBAndroid.sdk_System_Library_Frameworks_JavaFoundation.framework_java_JavaFoundationJava.jar'
>   '/Library/SBAndroid/Application
>   Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Platforms/Android.platform/Developer/SDKs/SBAndroid.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaFoundation.framework/java/JavaFoundationJava.jar'
>   Unable to locate an executable at
>   "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/bin/java"
>   (-1) FAILED: '/Library/SBAndroid/Application
>   Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Toolchains/Android.xctoolchain/usr/bin/dx'
>   --dex --num-threads=16 --output='/Users/thefreebird/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/First-doujqshtxvhdhsgbiqpivulzfhbi/Build/Products/Debug-sbandroid/dexed_libs/Library_SBAndroid_Application
>   Support_Developer_Shared_Xcode_Platforms_Android.platform_Developer_SDKs_SBAndroid.sdk_System_Library_Frameworks_GLActivityKit.framework_java_GLActivityJava.jar'
>   '/Library/SBAndroid/Application
>   Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Platforms/Android.platform/Developer/SDKs/SBAndroid.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/GLActivityKit.framework/java/GLActivityJava.jar'
>   Unable to locate an executable at
>   "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/bin/java"
>   (-1) FAILED: '/Library/SBAndroid/Application
>   Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Toolchains/Android.xctoolchain/usr/bin/dx'
>   --dex --num-threads=16 --output='/Users/thefreebird/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/First-doujqshtxvhdhsgbiqpivulzfhbi/Build/Products/Debug-sbandroid/dexed_libs/Library_SBAndroid_Application
>   Support_Developer_Shared_Xcode_Platforms_Android.platform_Developer_SDKs_SBAndroid.sdk_System_Library_Frameworks_AndroidKit.framework_java_AndroidKit
>   Java.jar' '/Library/SBAndroid/Application
>   Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Platforms/Android.platform/Developer/SDKs/SBAndroid.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AndroidKit.framework/java/AndroidKit
>   Java.jar' Unable to locate an executable at
>   "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/bin/java"
>   (-1) FAILED: '/Library/SBAndroid/Application
>   Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Toolchains/Android.xctoolchain/usr/bin/dx'
>   --dex --num-threads=16 --output='/Users/thefreebird/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/First-doujqshtxvhdhsgbiqpivulzfhbi/Build/Products/Debug-sbandroid/dexed_libs/Library_SBAndroid_Application
>   Support_Developer_Shared_Xcode_Platforms_Android.platform_Developer_SDKs_SBAndroid.sdk_....lib_annotations.jar'
>   '/Library/SBAndroid/Application
>   Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Platforms/Android.platform/Developer/lib/annotations.jar'
>   Unable to locate an executable at
>   "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/bin/java"
>   (-1) FAILED: '/Library/SBAndroid/Application
>   Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Toolchains/Android.xctoolchain/usr/bin/dx'
>   --dex --num-threads=16 --output='/Users/thefreebird/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/First-doujqshtxvhdhsgbiqpivulzfhbi/Build/Products/Debug-sbandroid/dexed_libs/Library_SBAndroid_Application
>   Support_Developer_Shared_Xcode_Platforms_Android.platform_Developer_SDKs_SBAndroid.sdk_System_Library_Frameworks_CoreJava.framework_java_CoreJavaJava.jar'
>   '/Library/SBAndroid/Application
>   Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Platforms/Android.platform/Developer/SDKs/SBAndroid.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreJava.framework/java/CoreJavaJava.jar'
>   Unable to locate an executable at
>   "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/bin/java"
>   (-1) ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed. Error: command failed:
>   '/Library/SBAndroid/Application
>   Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Toolchains/Android.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ninja'
>   Command /Library/SBAndroid/Application
>   Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/APPPlatformBuildSystem.xcplugin/Contents/Resources/package-apk.py failed with exit code 1

Command /Library/SBAndroid/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/APPPlatformBuildSystem.xcplugin/Contents/Resources/package-apk.py failed with exit code 1

Kindly help me to solve the issue..

Thanks & Regards.

Comment: Clear the log to make it more readable